# Swarm task doesn't wait for container exit (when constraints don't meet or update)

Tags: docker, containers, task, swarm

recently I investigate topics around managing tasks by swarm.
I don't review swarm source code yet, but it seems that swarm doesn't wait for the containers exit (on worker node) - it changes the task status to shutdown / rejectected (depending on reason to finish the tasks).

Is it (and how) possible to force swarm to really wait to exit of container that do the task?

I run in same time in separate console windows connected to my swarm cluster:

1. on worker NODE_XYZ: `watch -n 1 'docker ps -a --format "{{.Names}}\t{{.State}} \t{{.Status}}" | grep <part_of_the_tasks_name>'` AND
2. on manager node:  `watch -n 1 'docker node ps NODE_XYZ --format "{{.Name}}\t{{.DesiredState}}\t{{.CurrentState}}"  | grep <part_of_the_tasks_name>'

In next step, I remove label that is requied by the task constaints.

I observed that `docker node ps` lost tasks in very short time, but task containers are still running and visible by `docker ps` on worker node. (My task can take up to from seconds to many minutes to end dependend on given workload).

When I restore label required by the task constraint, in `docker node ps` tasks become visible, but in `docker ps` (on worker node) there are more tasks than should be - there are new running tasks and old (also running) to end.

When service is scaled down, swarm task waits for container correctly in `remove` desired state.

1. I expect that swarm task has status, code, or something like that, that allow determine is task waiting for container exit when desired state is `shutdown`.
2. I expect that swarm doesn't create new containers and respect cpu/memory reservations until old tasks are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two ways (workarounds) to detect that swarm task (and underlaying container) really finish its work:

1. Use agent on every swarm node to detect state of container
2. Analyze logs for last n minutes/seceonds (dependend on worklow) - when there is no logs or last log line contains given phrase (like `Bye!`) I assumed that container stops.

After some investigation, I choose second option that checks last line of logs in given duration:

```golang
func isStoppedCheckByLogs(
    ctx context.Context,
    noLogsTimeout time.Duration,    // when no logs found in this duration, we assume that task is ended
    endMessages []string,       // collection of messages like `Bye!` or `Stopped.` - they should be last messages before container stop.
    t swarm.Task,
    cli *docker.Client) (bool, string) {

    unix := time.Now().UTC().Unix()

    lastLog, err := cli.TaskLogs(ctx, t.ID, types.ContainerLogsOptions{
        ShowStdout: true,
        ShowStderr: true,
        Since:      fmt.Sprintf("%d", unix-int64(noLogsTimeout.Seconds())),
        Timestamps: false,
        Follow:     false,
        Tail:       "1",
        Details:    false,
    })

    if err != nil {
        return true, fmt.Sprintf("task logs error: %s", err)
    }

    defer lastLog.Close()

    lastData, err := io.ReadAll(lastLog)

    if err != nil {
        return true, fmt.Sprintf("read data error: %s", err)
    }

    lastLogLine := string(lastData)

    if len(lastLogLine) == 0 {
        return true, "last log line not found or empty"
    }

    for _, end := range endMessages {
        if len(end) == 0 {
            continue
        }

        if strings.Contains(lastLogLine, end) {
            return true, fmt.Sprintf("last log line '%s' contains '%s'", lastLogLine, end)
        }
    }

    return false, fmt.Sprintf("last log line: '%s'", lastLogLine)
}
```